# Header won't touch the top.

Tags: html, css

My header won't touch the top of my page. I've tried padding: 0px; in both my header div and body. Nothing will move it. I've adding in html to the css and tried margin:0px and padding:0px;. I was reading about using a CSS reset, but not sure if anyone has had success in that.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">

<head>

<title>Home</title>

</head>
<body>
<div class = "background">

<div class = "header">
<h1 class="Name">Title</h1>
<ul class="header">
<li>Home</li>
<li>About</li>
<li>Portfolio</li>
<li>Contact</li>
</ul>

</div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
background-color: gray;}

.header {
width: auto;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
background-color: black;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: try `html,body{margin:0; padding:0}`

Comment: What is the html for background? You should post a jsfiddle.

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>` is causing it. how to fix it? I have no idea

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>` is the standard html5 doctype declaration. I assure you this is not causing it (well, I assure you this is not a problem is probably the better way of saying it. you should definitely use this doctype for standard html5)

Comment: @KaiQing copy his code and remove it. but I guess I should have said, "something in your code is causing `<!DOCTYPE html>` to create whitespace". if you add `* { margin: 0; padding : 0; }` to the CSS it will fix it.

Comment: Removing it just means you have no doctype declared, which means the padding removal is an artifact of invalid code and not necessarily that the doctype was a problem. as my comment says, the standard padding/margin reset is `html,body{padding:0; margin:0}` - if the problem persists with that in place, consider the h1 will also have margins and padding on it and is likely the first element rendered. In that case, add `.header h1{margin-top:0; padding-top:0}`

Answer (score 2):

You can try absolutely positioning the header like so:

```
.header {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}
```

This will position the header in comparison to the viewport using the left & top dimensions as the offset.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w06fn6wn/

Answer (score 2):

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xdxrt72c/1/)

```
 * { margin: 0; padding : 0; }

body{
  background-color: gray;}

.header {
  width: auto;
  background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: only problem with this is you're resetting the margins and padding for every element. OP will then have to redeclare padding and margins for all block level elements where it is commonly expected. p, h1-6, ul, li, etc

Answer (score 0):

Add a reset to the top of mystyle.css

```
*{margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try in body

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```